# Twitter: where can I see my "liked" Moments?

Tags: twitter

When I "like" (or fav) a twit on Twitter, I can see it in my "Liked" tab. But if I "like" a moment, where are they saved? I haven't been able to find it anywhere in Twitter's UI.

Answer (score -1):

there is also Moments tab...

- go to **[twitter.com](https://twitter.com)** and log in
- click on **Moments** in the top bar or use this link **[twitter.com/i/moments](https://twitter.com/i/moments)** or click on your profile picture at the top bar and select **Moments** from the drop-down list

if you are on mobile...

- click **Settings** then select **Moments**

Comment: That's for Moments that you created yourself, isn't it? I'm talking about "liking" Moments made by someone else. Once you "like" them, where do you find them?

Comment: @PaulJ I believe its also for what you want. did you try it?

Comment: Yes. I "liked" a Moment by someone else, but it doesn't appear there. If I look for that Moment manually, it appears with the heart marked (that is, "liked" by me), but it doesn't show up in that tab at all.

Comment: Besides, the UI for that section says so explicitly: "You haven't created any Moment, When you do so, they will appear here".